# How to create Covariance matrix Mahalanobis distance in knn algo

Tags: matrix, covariance, knn

i have to implement [knn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbors_algorithm) algorithm for several kind of metrics, one of them is Mahalanobis metric. Usually to  create covariance matrix based at sample data (multiple rows) but in this case i need create covariance matrix when i know only my A vactor and Y vector where:

Y - is one or point from my knowed data
A - vector of arguments, point to which I equal others points

Maybe somebody can give me example how to calculate covariance matrix for two vectors?

Answer (score 0):

- *creating a search structure to perform NN-search based on special metrics:*

You might find this paper helpful:
http://www.machinelearning.org/archive/icml2008/papers/400.pdf

It describes a data structure to perform fast NN queries on Bregman divergences, including the Mahalanobis distance.

- *How to calculate a covariance matrix from two vectors*

I'm not totally sure I understand this question/problem correctly. What do you mean by "vector of arguments"? To compute a *n x n* covariance matrix that is not rank deficient, you need at least *(n+1)* points (that are coplanar on the respective *n-dimensional* hyperplane).